# NextJs - How to reuse dynamic routes?

Tags: next.js

I looked through the official docs but could not find a clear way to do this.
https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

I have a route where user can edit his/her profile:

```
/user/edit
```

The folder structure is `/edit/[userId]/index.jsx`

I am trying to reuse the same code/route to give an admin the ability to edit the profile.
The issue is when admin navigates to `/user/edit?userId=${user._id}` it still edits the admin's profile. The above is `req.query.userId`

How to pass userId to this route without using req.query:

```
/edit/[userId]/index.jsx
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be routing the admin to `/user/edit/<some-userId>` instead? Where `<some-userId>` is the target user's ID, not the admin's ID.